# Mожно-ли показывать AdSense в Android Webview?

Tags: android, webview, google-adsense

У меня есть сайт с рекламой AdSense. 
Я завернул его в стандартный Android WebView и в моем приложении стал отображаться сайт с рекламой.

В правилах AdSense написано:

> Publishers are not permitted to distribute Google ads or AdSense for
>   search boxes through software applications including, but not limited
>   to toolbars, browser extensions, and desktop applications. AdSense
>   code may only be implemented on web-based pages and **approved WebView
>   technologies**.

Источник: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295?hl=en#Ads_in_a_software_application

Вопросы: 
Что такое «approved WebView technologies»? 
Чем он отличаются от «not approved»?
Является-ли стандартный Webview Android «Approved»?

Могу-ли я показывать рекламу в стандартном WebView?

Нашел похожий вопрос, но ясного ответа на него нет:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11119654/android-adsense-in-webview-for-blackberry-playbook-android-runtime